# Cannot serialize member <x> because it is an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, deserialization, xml-serialization, neo4jclient

Follow on question from [Error with explicit conversion when using CollectAs<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563378/error-with-explicit-conversion-when-using-collectas/31566114#31566114)

Code from WebMethod

```
return client.Cypher
        .Match("(person:Person)")
        .Where((Person person) => person.Email == username)
        .OptionalMatch("(person)-[:SPEAKS]-(language:Language)")
        .OptionalMatch("(person)-[:CURRENT_LOCATION]-(country:Country)"
        .Return((person, language, country) => new ProfileObject
        {
            Person = person.As<Person>(),
            Language = language.CollectAs<Language>(),
            Country = country.CollectAs<Country>()
        }).Results.ToList();
```

Code from Country Class:

```
public class Language
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

New code from ProfileObject Class:

```
public class ProfileObject
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node<Language>> Language { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node<Country>> Country { get; set; }
}
```

This error only happens when I set ProfileObject to return  IEnumerable>, if I return it to just

```
public Country Country {get; set;}
```

then it works (but I obviously get duplicated Person entries for each Country object returned.

Anyone able to show me a solution to this problem that doesn't involve me ripping all of the code out and starting again?

**Update:**

> [InvalidOperationException: Neo4jClient.Node`1[Graph.Language] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.]
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member 'Graph.ProfileObject.Language' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Neo4jClient.Node`1[[Graph.Language, Graph, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Neo4jClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details.]
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type) +5451673
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type type) +69
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +125
>      System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo memberInfo) +89
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter) +618
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter) +378
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1799
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Graph.ProfileObject'.]
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1917
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateArrayElementsFromAttributes(ArrayMapping arrayMapping, XmlArrayItemAttributes attributes, Type arrayElementType, String arrayElementNs, RecursionLimiter limiter) +263
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportArrayLikeMapping(ArrayModel model, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter) +264
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +5456308
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +852
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +286
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'MyResult'.]
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +979
>      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) +133
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess) +240
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +2893
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Method ProfileServices.My can not be reflected.]
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +6173
>      System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod() +137
>      System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.ReflectBinding(ReflectedBinding reflectedBinding) +1776
>      System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.Reflect() +641
>      System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.ReflectInternal(ProtocolReflector[] reflectors) +685
>      System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.Reflect(Type type, String url) +118
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerType..ctor(Type type, String uri, Boolean excludeSchemeHostPortFromCachingKey) +230
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize() +434
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +122
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle request.]
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +320
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +171
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Failed to handle request.]
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +374
>      System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +209
>      System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +48
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +226
>      System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +145
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Both properties are filled by a list. Can't you change the type from ienumerable<country/language> to list<country/language>? That doesn't change the functionality

Comment: @Luc sadly not:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Neo4jClient.Node<Graph.Country>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Neo4jClient.Node<Graph.Country>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I had that thought too :(

Comment: Do you know what serializer is being used?  Is it `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: If you don't know, can you give the complete `ToString()` output of the exception, including the traceback?

Comment: For the compilation error when you change from ienumerable<country/language> to list<country/language> , you should try to use the ToList() method   .Return((person, language, country) => new ProfileObject
        {
            Person = person.As<Person>(),
            Language = language.CollectAs<Language>().ToList(),
            Country = country.CollectAs<Country>().ToList()
        }).Results.ToList();

Comment: @dbc to be honest no, this is a default C# web service with a single method in it, it was suggested below that is was XmlSerializer.

Comment: @Agalo, I get to different errors, depending on where I put ToList(), if it goes in the query I get unable to serialize... and if I put it on the profileobject I get the very not helpful error 'cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.' By the way, as far as I can see it does have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) uses [`DataContractSerializer`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter) to serialize to XML, however the error message `"Cannot serialize member <x> because it is an interface"` is [generated by `XmlSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property), so apparently you have switched to that.

You could consider switching back to `DataContractSerializer` as specified [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter), which can serialize properties of type `IEnumerable<T>` as long as the underlying type `T` can be serialized.

Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, you could modify your `ProfileObject` class to return proxy arrays for serialization without changing your underlying design:

```
public class ProfileObject
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Node<Language>> Language { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Node<Country>> Country { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Languages")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Language")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Node<Language>[] LanguageArray
    {
        get
        {
            if (Language == null)
                return null;
            return Language.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            Language = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("Countries")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Country")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Node<Country>[] CountryArray
    {
        get
        {
            if (Country == null)
                return null;
            return Country.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            Country = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

`XmlSerializer` will only serialize properties with public `get` and `set` methods.  Since `Node.Data` is get-only, it can't be serialized by `XmlSerializer`.

Since you only need to serialize the data and not the `Node<TData>`, and never need to deserialize, you can use linq to return transform your enumerable of nodes to an array of data for serialization as follows:

```
public static class NodeExtensions
{
    public static TData [] ToDataArray<TData>(this IEnumerable<Node<TData>> nodes)
    {
        if (nodes == null)
            return null;
        return nodes.Select(n => n.Data).ToArray();
    }
}

public class ProfileObject
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Node<Language>> Language { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Node<Country>> Country { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ArrayOfLanguage")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Language")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Language [] LanguageArray
    {
        get
        {
            return Language.ToDataArray();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("ArrayOfCountry")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Country")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Country [] CountryArray
    {
        get
        {
            return Country.ToDataArray();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lovely answer, very detailed and probably quite accurate, sadly no help to me, when I amend my code I get the error: 

Neo4jClient.Node`1[Graph.Language] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

As you can see Language *does* have a parameterless constructor.
As for using DataContractSerializer, I didn't make a change away from it as far as I know. I am going to review what is happening, there is no way I shouldn't be able to format the returned data, this seems to be my fault, maybe bad design. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Judging by the error I would hazard a guess that Neo4jClient.Node is *not*  parameterless, so in summary, I am busted. It would appear that I would need to make a constructor for Neo4jClient.Node that was parameterless, and I can't do that easily (I suppose I could download the source and make a new constructor, but for future updates this would be a *terrible* idea).
So, unless I have an 11th hour miracle it looks like this is not really possible.

Comment: Here is the code for Neo4jClient.Node: 
`namespace Neo4jClient
{
    public class Node<TNode> : IGremlinQuery, IHasNodeReference
    {
        readonly TNode data;
        readonly NodeReference<TNode> reference;

        public Node(TNode data, NodeReference<TNode> reference)
        {
            if (reference == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("reference");

            this.data = data;
            this.reference = reference;
        }`

Comment: And just for completeness, I added a parameterless constructor to Neo4jClient.Node, which did take away the error (the expected behaviour) but the result just contains empty nodes for Language and Country (obviously because we are not passing the node to get the data from).
`<Languages>
      <Language />
      <Language />
    </Languages>
    <Countries>
      <Country />
      <Country />
    </Countries>`

Comment: @ShaineFisher - Looking at the source code for `Node<TNode>` [here](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/blob/master/Neo4jClient/Node%60TNode.cs), the XML is empty because the `Data` and `Reference` properties are get-only.  1) Do you actually need to serialize the `Node<T>`, or would it be sufficient to serialize the underlying `T`?  2) Do you need to **deserialize**, or is it sufficient to serialize?

Comment: I only really need the data, specifically Country.Name and Language.Name, they are being consumed by a Flexclient, so no real need at this point to deserialize.

Comment: to continue from my previous comment, that is not only detailed, accurate and really well explained, it is perfect. Problem solved. I actually didn't know enough about Neo4jClient to make any real comment (apart from it is fantastic and the support is outstanding), it isn't my code, it is far more complex than I understand, and I would probably never have looked there for a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaineFisher I would strongly consider Tatham's advice from your last question and update `Neo4jClient` to the Pre-release version - you don't want to be passing around `Node` elements, and when the next version of `Neo4jClient` is released it won't be returning `Node<T>` for `CollectAs`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you shouldn't need to add any changes to the `Node<T>` class, it should deserialize everything fine.

So, this is my current setup:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileObject
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node<Language>> Language { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node<Country>> Country { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

You don't define `Country` or `Person` so I've made them up, but in essence I think it's pretty close. Now I initialize my db to have something like:

```
(PERSON)-[:SPEAKS]->(ENGLISH)
(PERSON)-[:SPEAKS]->(GERMAN)
(PERSON)-[:CURRENT_LOCATION]->(GERMANY)
```

First off, running your query 'as is' (i.e. Copied from this page directly) works fine for me, in terms of serialization - can you confirm that your `Language`, `Person`, `Country` and `ProfileObject` are as you've defined either with default constructors or explicit parameterless constructors?

As to what you're expecting back - I guess you're after a `ProfileObject` with 2 `Language` objects, and only 1 `Country`. Now, the query you write is converted to Cypher like this:

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WHERE (person.Email = "THE EMAIL ADDRESS HERE")
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:SPEAKS]-(language:Language)
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:CURRENT_LOCATION]-(country:Country)
RETURN person AS Person, collect(language) AS Language, collect(country) AS Country
```

If you run this in the Neo4j manager (localhost:7474) and switch to the 'rows' view (from the graph one) you'll see you actually get returned the data in the form you're getting in the Client.

I would tweak the query in the neo4j management view until you get what you want. It might be worth not returning `CollectAs` and doing a LINQ `.Group` afterwards.

Comment: we have the same setup, you have it right, and the data that comes back is correct, Tatham gave me some good advice to get tot his point, but as I said in the other post() I then get Unable to serialize because Country is an interface, which is why this thread started. It appears that the XMLSerializer is not liking trying to serialize Neo4jClient.Node<Country>, country isn't the issue because if I don't use IEnumberable<Node<Country>> it doesn't error. Other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563378/error-with-explicit-conversion-when-using-collectas/

Comment: The only difference between my results and yours is that I threw in 2 Countries for CURRENT_LOCATION, just for testing.