# Export object to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I have an object like this:

```
public partial class CableApplication : StateObject
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public CableApplication()
    {
        this.CableProperties = new HashSet<CableProperty>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public byte[] ts { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CableProperty> CableProperties { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

which is created in `.edmx` file automatically in database-first Visual Studio C# project. I want to export all the data of `CableApplication` into an XML file.

I wrote this code in the service:

```
public string ExportToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\temp\\check.xml");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, obj);
        writer.Close();

        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }           
}
```

And this code in the frontend project:

```
private void exporToXMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ICableService client = new CableService())
    {                
        var applications = client.GetCableApplications(searchList.ToArray(), null, "").ToList();    // I get the list of cable Applications . works fine

        var str = client.ExportToXml(applications);              
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot serialize member 'Cable1Layer.Domain.CableApplication.CableProperties' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Cable1Layer.Domain.CableProperty, Cable1Layer.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details
>
> There was an error reflecting type 'Cable1Layer.Domain.CableApplication'

How should I serialiaze this object?

Comment: Ca you include the specificatin of the class `CableProperty` as well, please?

Comment: @JayV: it is an object with its own Properties and naviagtion properties

Comment: You defined a `CableApplication`, and the function `client.GetCableApplications(...).ToList()` does return a list of those things?

Comment: @Luuk: yes,  var applications has the the list of applications fetched from db successfull without error

Comment: You cannot serialize a List.  A well formed xml has only one root tag.  You list has multiple tags at root.  What may work is :            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename", settings);

Comment: @jdweng - *You cannot serialize a List* -- you certainly can serialize a `List<T>` with `XmlSerializer`.  The result will be an XML document with a root element `<ArrayOfX>` where `X` is the XML root name of the type `T`, e.g. `<ArrayOfCableApplication>` for the type in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The innermost error message (not shown in your question) is self explanatory:

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member `CableApplication.CableProperties` of type `ICollection<CableProperty>` **because it is an interface**.

`XmlSerializer` cannot serialize interfaces because, not being concrete types, they cannot be constructed during deserialization.  For more see

- *[Cannot serialize member.... because it is an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3632769)*
- *[Cannot serialize member <x> because it is an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31630614)*

As a workaround you could introduce a serializable surrogate property and mark the original property with [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute), however since your class was auto-generated from an [.edmx file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first) you probably don't want to modify any of the auto-generated code.  Thus what you can do is:

- Take advantage of the fact that `CableApplication` was generated as a **partial** class to add a serializable surrogate property in a manually created partial file.
- Use [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides) to suppress serialization of the non-serializable interface property.

To do this, first extend `CableProperties` as follows:

```
public partial class CableApplication
{
    public CableProperty [] CablePropertiesArray
    {
        get { return CableProperties.ToArray(); }
        set
        {
            CableProperties.Clear();
            if (value != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in value)
                    CableProperties.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the following `XmlSerializer` factory:

```
public static class XmlSerializerFactory
{
    readonly static object lockObject = new object();
    readonly static Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> SerializerDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>();
    
    public static XmlSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            if (SerializerDictionary.TryGetValue(type, out serializer))
                return serializer;
            var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides()
                .AddCableApplicationOverrides()
                // Add customizations for other types as needed here.
                ;
            SerializerDictionary.Add(type, serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, overrides));
            return serializer;
        }
    }
    
    static XmlAttributeOverrides AddCableApplicationOverrides(this XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
    {
        overrides.Add(typeof(CableApplication), 
                      "CableProperties", // Use nameof(CableApplication.CableProperties) if available in your C# version
                      new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true });
        overrides.Add(typeof(CableApplication), 
                      "CablePropertiesArray", // Use nameof(CableApplication.CablePropertiesArray) if available in your C# version
                      new XmlAttributes { XmlArray = new XmlArrayAttribute { ElementName = "CableProperties" } }); // Use nameof(CableApplication.CableProperties) if available in your C# version
        return overrides;
    }
}
```

And finally modify `ExportToXml<T>(T obj)` to use the serializer factory:

```
public string ExportToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    {
        // You never actually write anything to the StreamWriter so I'm not sure what is going in here.  
        // I commented this code out since I did not have a d:\temp\check.xml file
        //TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter( @"d:\\temp\\check.xml");
        var serializer = XmlSerializerFactory.CreateSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, obj);
        //writer.Close();

        return stringwriter.ToString();
    }           
}
```

Note that, when constructing serializer using `XmlAttributeOverrides`, it is necessary to statically cache and reuse the serializer for reasons explained in *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V9GVTL).